# Gatsby wildcard route

Tags: reactjs, redirect, routes, gatsby

Is it not possible to route to the same component with a wildcard path?
If in React I have something like:

```
<Router>
   <Switch>
      <Route path="/path/:id" children={<Component />} />
   </Switch>
</Router>
```

all the requests:

```
/path/123
/path/123/p
/path/123/p/1
```

will route to the same `/path/123`

How can I tell Gatsby to do the same?

```
createPage({
  path: `/path/123/*`,
  component,
  context
})
```

Or what is the solution to this problem, a redirect engine of some sorts?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [client-only routes](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/routing/client-only-routes-and-user-authentication/). Given a page (or template if it's created from `gatsby-node.js`) you can:

```
import React from "react"
import { Router } from "@reach/router"
import Layout from "../components/Layout"
import SomeComponent from "../components/SomeComponent"

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Router basepath="/app">
        <SomeComponent path="/path" />
      </Router>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default App
```

*Note: assuming a `src/pages/app/[...].js` page ([File System Route API structure](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/routing/file-system-route-api/)).*

When a page loads, Reach Router looks at the path prop of each component nested under `<Router />`, and chooses one to render that best matches `window.location` (you can learn more about how routing works from the [`@reach/router`](https://reach.tech/router/api/Router) documentation).

Alternatively, you can use an automated approach (plugin: [`gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths`](https://www.gatsbyjs.cn/packages/gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths/)) by:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths`,
  options: { prefixes: [`/path/*`] },
},
```

Which will validate all routes under `/path`.

Or for a more customizable approach, in your `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  // page.matchPath is a special key that's used for matching pages
  // only on the client.
  if (page.path.match(/^\/path/)) {
    page.matchPath = "/path/*"

    // Update the page.
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

*Disclaimer: These routes will exist on the client only and will not correspond to `index.html` files in an app’s built assets. If you’d like site users to be able to visit client routes directly, you’ll need to set up your server to handle those routes appropriately.*